# Do not close the alertdialog by clicking on a button - Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I've an alertdialog any options and with 2 buttons. I don't want close the dialog when I push on the second button (only stop a sound).

Is there any property to maintain the dialog open?

Thank you so much!

Code:

```
        public void creaDialogTo(){

            final String[] tonos = {"thinks.mp3", "life.mp3", "war.mp3"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.setTitle("Select");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(tones, -1,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    tone=tones[item];
                    sound1 =new SoundManager(getApplicationContext());
                    sound1.loadSound(tones[item]);


                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            pref.setTone(tone);

                            sound1.stopsound();

                        }
                    });
            builder.setNeutralButton("Stop sound",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        sound1.stopsound();

                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show(); 

    }
```

Comment: can post the code what you are using for alert dialog

Comment: then call builder.dismiss() at confirm button only. no need to call the dismissal method for stop button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess, You are displaying AlertDialog, with default buttons Positive and Negative. instead, you can create a Dialog, and set a layout as contentView of this dialog, with having two buttons, manually. Here you would need to define all the definition of the button click event, and no default button will occur. So, If you are not dismissing dialog on a button click, simply dont invoke dialog.dismiss(), on button click.

Edit: Neutral Button by default dismiss the dialog, try changing it as negative button, if it still wont work, then please apply solution, I have written above.

Comment: The negative button does the same :(

Comment: Please create a Dialog, and Set ContentView of this dialog to a layout having these buttons.