# Validation on EditText entered in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener

In the function below, I want to force the user to enter some text in the EditText box "password". If the user leaves it empty, I want the ALertDialog to NOT go away, and may be jsut change the title and message.

I know I need to do something in the onClick(...) function but not able to get it right. I have seen other solutions in SO but haven't found something to exactly work. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
public void setKeywordDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder setPasswordDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    setPasswordDialog.setTitle("You must set a password");
    setPasswordDialog.setMessage("Please set a password. You can change it anytime. You can receive this phone's location by texting this password");

    //Add an EditText box
    final EditText password = new EditText(this);
    password.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    setPasswordDialog.setView(password);



    setPasswordDialog.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
             //<<HERE I WANT TO CHECK IF "password.getText().toString()" is empty - AlertDialogBox should not close>>

        }
    });

    setPasswordDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: You can use `if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText().toString()))`

Comment: Yes but what inside the if condition....my goal is that the alert dialog should not disappear till some next is entered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362928/do-not-close-the-alertdialog-by-clicking-on-a-button-android. search on stackoverflow you will few more similar ones

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setKeywordDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder setPasswordDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    setPasswordDialog.setTitle("You must set a password");
    setPasswordDialog.setMessage("Please set a password. You can change it anytime. You can receive this phone's location by texting this password");

//Add an EditText box
final EditText password = new EditText(this);
password.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
setPasswordDialog.setView(password);



setPasswordDialog..setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

setPasswordDialog.show();
setPasswordDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

@Override
public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

    Button b = d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(everything is ok)
            d.dismiss();
            else
            //do some changes
        }
    });
}
});
}
```